# Only insert email when present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I'm using twitter and facebook to connect to a website. When the provider is facebook I want to add the users email to the database field when its twitter there should be no email. The code below keeps timing out my server.

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid']).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.profile_data = auth.info
      user.email = auth.info.email unless user.email.nil?

      user.token = auth['credentials']['token'] unless auth['credentials'].nil?
      user.secret = auth['credentials']['secret'] unless auth['credentials'].nil?
    end
  end
```

I've also tried

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid']).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.profile_data = auth.info
      user.email = auth.info.email unless auth.info.email?

      user.token = auth['credentials']['token'] unless auth['credentials'].nil?
      user.secret = auth['credentials']['secret'] unless auth['credentials'].nil?
    end
  end
```

Error on heroku:

```
2012-08-21T23:30:07+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.myapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user.email = auth.info.email unless auth.info.email.blank?
```

This checks for the auth hash for nil and empty values.

Comment: Thanks it still keeps breaking heroku. From looking at the logs I get: 2012-08-21T23:30:07+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.myapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0